# Getting feature from coordinates in geotools

Tags: wfs, java, geotools

I'm working on web services in Java and using GeoTools java api for wfs operations.

I have a wfs store and a lot of features in it. I do some operations via geotools wfs api for example buffer, intersect etc. My problem is not building feature from points. I'm using geotools for building my geo web services and want to create a web service method that must use two parameters(lat and lon) and return content of a feature.

This returned feature must be perfectly matched with given latitude and longitude so this coordinates should point out this feature

How can I do that ?

Such as wms,wfs ogc services are rest apis and return xml responses. I don't want to use this services  with http request or rest api clients.Also I don't want to parse directly response document at the same time doing all operations in client side is not useful for my app. I want to build my web service composition for some defined operations in wfs,wms and etc.

Comment: So you're trying to build a web service (server side)? Why not just use the existing WFS? Do you need some special API? Right now, it isn't clear what you've already tried and what the problem is. Can you edit your question to fix up those details please?

Comment: I've edited my question @BradHards. What is your suggestion now?

Comment: You're still telling us what you don't want to do, rather than describing what you do need to do, what you have already done, and what the problem is. At the moment, you're not giving us enough to provide a specific, useful answer. Remember this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.

Comment: Basicly I want to use GetFeatureInfo request in server side without http reques t. I must send two parameters that contains lat and lon value. My service should return a feature info response. If you read carely, you got what I want to do. I'm not duscussing just explaining my problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can query a WFS service without a HTTP request. Maybe someone else is smarter than me and can figure out what you are asking - I give up.